# Réponse à "Bonne chance..."

Tags: usage, correspondance

J'ai posé une candidature pour un poste. La candidature étant tardive j'ai reçus la réponse :

> Le poste a été déjà pourvu. Bonne chance dans vos démarches de recherche d'emploi.

Comment puis-je remercier le recruteur (lequel je ne connais pas) pour :

> **Bonne chance** dans vos démarches de recherche d'emploi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En général, ce genre de mail n'attend pas de réponse en retour. C'est une formule très classique de réponse négative à une candidature.

Cependant la réponse à `Bonne chance` est `merci`. Mais ici, si je tenais à être polie , je remercierai plus la réponse que le voeux de bonne chance.

Comment: C'est ça. Et comme tu as chevauché mon commentaire ci-dessus je le supprime :p